# put request with _method="PUT" recognized as POST under symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, request, put

In my symfony 2 application, my form request with a method set to PUT are not recognized correctly anymore.

I get the following error :

```
No route found for "POST /social/post/create_post/blog": Method Not Allowed (Allow: PUT, GET, HEAD)
```

When I check the profiler, I have :

```
Key         Value
_method     PUT
appbundle_social_post_blog  
[
  name => sfsQDF, 
  content => <p>SDFSDF DFSQ&nbsp;</p>, 
  tags => [
    0 => 4
  ], 
  _token => tE9niM9LK8gRDdSOEPsgIFqqrkY5iDGKY30HFHLycmM
]
```

It worked well until today, I don't know why.
It's only happening in dev environment.

Does anyone have an explanation for this ?

Comment: what does app/console router:debug give you ?

Comment: well, I have an annotation with * @Method({"PUT", "GET"}) on my controller action and this is correctly reflected in the router:debug : only GET and PUT methods are accepted for this route. I don't understand why it suddenly stopped recognizing PUT requests

Comment: ok, found it! I had changed my app_dev.php to include AppCache.php. This somehow changed how PUT methods were handled...